# VSCode Golang dlv debug error for version mismatch

Tags: go

On MacOS, `brew upgrad`-ed upgraded golang to version 1.14. Able to run unit test but debug fails with message

```
# errors
compile: version "go1.12.13" does not match go tool version "go1.14.2"
# unicode/utf16
compile: version "go1.12.13" does not match go tool version "go1.14.2"
# unicode/utf8
compile: version "go1.12.13" does not match go tool version "go1.14.2"
# internal/race
compile: version "go1.12.13" does not match go tool version "go1.14.2"
# container/list
....
```

`go env` output shows go version as **1.14.2**

Answer (score -2):

Fixed. Had a stale go bin reference in VSCode User settings.

Comment: This is not helpful.